# Cassandra writes - How many nodes?

Tags: cassandra

I'm probably just missing something here, but my search terms have all been to general to get meaningful results.

Assume RF = Replication Factor

When I write a value to the database, does it write the value to RF nodes or does it write it to one node and replicate it RF nodes?

Comment: What's your consistency level?

Comment: A write will always propagate to all replica nodes. The consistency level drives _when it does so_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your question is really "how many nodes eventually have a copy of the data I write", then the answer is RF, *not* RF+1.

RF=1 means you have no redundancy and only have a single copy of your data.

Comment: Thanks! This is the straight-forward answer I was looking for :)

Answer (score 4):

That depends on the request you send. In the write request you can specify the consistency level:

- ALL: it will write to all RF nodes before returning
- QUORUM: it will write to a quorum of nodes before returning
- ONE: it writes to one node before returning. After returning it waits response from RF-1 nodes.
- LOCAL_QUORUM

...

See other possible values here: http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/dml/dml_config_consistency_c.html

Eventually all RF nodes will have the written data.

Comment: Latest docs are: https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/architecture/dynamo.html?highlight=consistancy#tunable-consistency